# Редирект на страницу с результатами ajax

Tags: ajax, php

День добрый. Вопрос следующий.
Как послать POST в php скрипт с главной страницы и сразу перенаправить пользователя на страницу результата с результатами. 
Вся проблема в том, что страница результата полностью на ajax работает.
Не хочется в php делать еще один обработчик.

Может есть возможность передачи переменной с одной страницы в скрипт ajax другой страницы?

Comment: чет как-то всё запутано, думаю cookie ваш код не испортит :)

Comment: лучше в сессию всё положить.

Comment: @dimka, как данные  из сессии окажутся в запросе ajax ? можно куки, можно кодированный $_POST в div или скрипт положить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему другим способом. Передаю из шапки ссылку вида `ссылка&опция=значение` и выполняю на нее редирект, а на итоговой странице в событии `onload` проверяю если есть `GET['опция']`, то выполнить ajax запрос и вуаля, при переходе на страницу все работает как мне было нужно)